# Keywords with and without @ in Swift

Tags: programming-languages, swift, keyword

In Swift, sometimes, keywords are plain keywords, and some others start with an `@`.

For instance, `weak`, `unowned`, `inout`, `class` are plain. But `@final`, `@lazy` start with `@`.

Sometimes, we even have both! `prefix` and `@prefix`, `infix` and `@infix` for instance.

It is not entirely an Objective-C inheritance since we have `@class` and not `class` in Objective-C. I could understand why we have `class` and not `@class` in Swift, but since we have `@final` or `@lazy` , I would have thought that it should be `@weak` and not `weak`.

Why this choice? Is there a kind of intuitive way that should tell: "hey, it is logical that this keyword starts with `@`?

Even if I think with a preprocessor perspective in mind, it is not obvious that `@` would call a kind of specific preprocessor before compilation (e.g. `@final` is not really a kind of preprocessor directive).

Comment: You are not alone. Apple itself didn't/doesn't know the difference between them. They recently changed `@final` to `final`, `@lazy` to `lazy`, etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I found that in the XCode 6 beta 4 release notes: "The `@final`, `@lazy`, `@optional`, and `@required` attributes have been converted to declaration modifiers, specified without an @ sign." If you write your answer as a normal one, I will upvote it :)

Comment: And in beta 5 release notes: "The `@prefix`, `@infix`, and `@postfix` attributes have been changed to declaration modifiers, 
so they are no longer spelled with an @ sign"

Answer (score 9):

`@`-prefixed items in Swift are not *keywords*, these are *attributes*.

Apple's book on Swift says that

> *Attributes* provide more information about a declaration or type. There are two kinds of attributes in Swift, those that apply to declarations and those that apply to types.

Some attributes (such as `@objc(isEnabled)`) accept parameters.

The main difference between attributes and keywords is that keywords tell the compiler what you are defining (a class, a method, a property, a variable, and so on), while attributes tell the compiler in what contexts you intend to use that definition. For example, you would use a `func` keyword to tell the compiler that you are defining a function, and decorate that function with an `@infix` attribute to tell the compiler that you plan to use that function as an infix operator.